# How can I prompt a user for precise location when only approximate location is authorized in Android 12 or later?

Tags: android, android-permissions

As Google said.If your app requests the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION runtime permission, you should also request the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission to handle the case where the user grants approximate location access to your app.
I want to show a dialog to prompt user that the function needs precise location.But I found that if the user only authorized the approximate location.For ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions using `shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale()` method returns false although at this point it can be requested normally.
So,my question is. In this case, how to determine whether ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION authorization popover can be displayed.

I've tried using Gensei or frameworks like RXPermissions, and they haven't met my expectations

Comment: Dont know where you are complaining about. You should first ask for COARSE. And only when the user granted that ask for FINE. Thats all.

Comment: Friend, you don't understand.According to Google, when I need a precise location, I should request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.Instead of applying for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION first and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION later.It's not in conflict.So my question is.When I apply for both permissions,If the user only gives the fuzzy location.For ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions using shouldshowrequestpermissionrationale().It's return false.At this point, how do I decide if I should direct the user to the Settings page to open manually, or if I can continue to apply for permissions

Comment: `You should first ask for COARSE. And only when the user granted that ask for FINE. Thats all. `

Comment: OK, fine. You don't understand what I'm asking

Comment: Indeed. Not a word. And no code.

Comment: This is a logical understanding problem, it has nothing to do with code